# WinNt.h compile errors

Tags: c++, eclipse, winsock2

I have a new C++ project in Eclipse. I had to add all the include paths manually, and I must have screwed something up. Here is my code:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I can compile the same code in Visual Studio no problem, but I get many and sundry compiler errors in Eclipse. Am I forgetting to include something? Or am I including too much? Any ideas?

I did include the WS2_32 library, as well.

I'm on Windows 8 x64 using the msvc 2010 compiler.

I searched for this for quite awhile, but all the answers were about including winsock before you include windows.h, but I'm not including windows.h at all. Plus, this exact same code compiles correctly in MSVC; therefore, I have a setting wrong in Eclipse.

At the risk of getting tl;dr'ed, here is the spew:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1243) : error C2065: 'SAL_sameIRQL' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1246) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1246) : error C2513: 'int' : no variable declared before '='
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1246) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1246) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__stdcall'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1246) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1246) : error C2377: 'EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION' : redefinition; typedef cannot be overloaded with any other symbol
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\excpt.h(40) : see declaration of 'EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1252) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1254) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1254) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1254) : error C2365: 'EXCEPTION_ROUTINE' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1247) : see declaration of 'EXCEPTION_ROUTINE'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1254) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(10749) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Handler'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(10749) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(10749) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(16638) : error C2144: syntax error : 'PSLIST_ENTRY' should be preceded by ','
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(16646) : error C2144: syntax error : 'PSLIST_ENTRY' should be preceded by ','
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\heapapi.h(124) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_SA_annotes1'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\heapapi.h(125) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\heapapi.h(125) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\processthreadsapi.h(204) : error C2144: syntax error : 'LPVOID' should be preceded by ','
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(189) : error C2065: 'SAL_preferredFunction' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(192) : error C2448: '_SA_annotes2' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(192) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__stdcall'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(351) : error C2065: 'COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(351) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'NameType'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(351) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(351) : error C2491: 'GetComputerNameExA' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(354) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(361) : error C2065: 'COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(361) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'NameType'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(361) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(361) : error C2491: 'GetComputerNameExW' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(364) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(383) : error C2065: 'COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(383) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'NameType'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(383) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(383) : error C2491: 'SetComputerNameExW' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(385) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\memoryapi.h(429) : error C2065: 'MEMORY_RESOURCE_NOTIFICATION_TYPE' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\memoryapi.h(430) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'NotificationType'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\memoryapi.h(430) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\memoryapi.h(430) : error C2491: 'CreateMemoryResourceNotification' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\memoryapi.h(430) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\memoryapi.h(536) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'PWIN32_MEMORY_RANGE_ENTRY'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\threadpoolapiset.h(341) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'PTP_WIN32_IO_CALLBACK'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(54) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BEM_FREE_INTERFACE_CALLBACK'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(64) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(64) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(73) : error C2065: 'BEM_REFERENCE' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(73) : error C2065: 'reference' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(74) : error C2065: 'BEM_REFERENCE' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(75) : error C2065: 'copiedReference' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(75) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(75) : error C2078: too many initializers
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(81) : error C2065: 'BEM_REFERENCE' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(82) : error C2065: 'reference' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(82) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(82) : error C2182: 'BemFreeReference' : illegal use of type 'void'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(82) : fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

Comment: There are many things in the Windows headers from Microsoft that depend on the existence and/or value of compiler defined preprocessor symbols.  Perhaps you are missing some of those that are critical to your build?  I generally find that poking around near where the errors occur will lead me to the missing symbol, often after tracking down the origin of a typedef or two.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, try using the 7.1 or 7.0 SDK instead of 8.0/8.1.  We are having similar issues with the 8.0 SDK.

Comment: Is it possible to mix the 7.x and 8.x SDKs? 8.1's winnt.h is causing me issues and 7.1 doesn't have winapifamily.h which is required for SDL 2.0.3! So I can either use the current version of SDL or I can have network support... not fair.